# using ^[A-Za-z ][A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&* ]*$ reg validation password how apply length in c# code behind

Tags: c#, passwords

Using password regex validation:

```
^[A-Za-z ][A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&* ]*$
```

How I apply length into that in c# code behind server?

Comment: You should describe the problem and show what has been done so far to solve it. What's wrong with your current code? You get error or incorrect length value?

Comment: Its pretty simple what he is saying. He wants to apply Regex Password Limit (Password Length) into the Regex he has provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
^[A-Za-z ][A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&* ]{8,15}*$
```

This {8,15} means that the length could be between 8 to 15

Comment: throw error Additional information: parsing "^[A-Za-z ][A-Za-z0-9!@#$%^&* ]{7,10}*$" - Nested quantifier *.

Answer (score 0):

Well this might be what you are expecting

```
public static bool IsValidPassword (string input)
        {
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"(?=^.{8,12}$)((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]))^.*");

            if (match.Success && match.Index == 0 && match.Length == input.Length)
                return true;
            else
                return false;

        }
```